# Difference between alias rm and /bin/rm

Tags: shell

What is the difference between using `/bin/rm abc.txt` and the times when sometimes you have to `alias rm` which is then performed with `rm abc.txt`

Comment: I guess it depends on what `rm` is aliased to...

Comment: I thought `alias rm` is another extra command of `rm` until the answer posted by jforberg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`/bin/rm` will always refer to the binary `rm` command on your system. If you just write `rm abc.txt` one of these may happen:

- Your shell implements `rm` directly as a builtin function or there is a shell function called `rm` (no external command is run).
- `rm` has previously been aliased (with `alias rm=<substituted-command>`) to mean something different. Usually the aliased command is similar in function but it does not have to be.
- If none of the above is applicable, the shell looks up the external command in `/bin` and runs it.

You can use `alias` to see all defined aliases. Also check out the `command -V` shell builtin which can tell you if a given command is an external command, shell function, builtin or special builtin.

Comment: Big thanks for the informative article. I guess I have to check up on the `alias rm` in my computer on Monday, seeing that both commands can be used when a particular error comes up.

Comment: I'm not aware of any shell that implements `rm` as a built-in function. One case you've forgotten is that an `rm` executable exists in some directory that precedes `/bin` in `$PATH` (for example `/usr/local/bin/rm`). For bash, `type -a rm` gives more information than `command -V rm`.

Comment: Just found out that the `alias rm` in my computer function is as follows: `Usage: /bin/rm [OPTION]... FILE...` which is similar to the /bin/rm method in a sense, I guess? However, as I tried using the `-a` or `-v` methods, I am getting no results at all or I would get an error message stating that `-v: Command not found`

Comment: @yan You didn't tell us what operating system and shell you were using, so I sort of assumed Linux and Bash. On that platform, command -V <name> will give you information about the type of a command. Make sure you get the big V, not the small.

Answer (score 1):

A typical reason to create an alias for `rm` is to add the `-i` or `-I` option. In "interactive" mode `rm` will ask for confirmation before deleting anything.

```
$ alias rm="/bin/rm -i"

$ rm myfile
rm: remove regular file ‘myfile’? _
```

Comment: Not recommended. That gets you accustomed to having a safety net instead of actually thinking when you type `rm`